How to infer or find basic types for return values in @solana/web3.js v2 library?
I’m working on a project using the Solana web3.js v2 library, and I’ve run into a challenge with types. Specifically, I’m trying to infer or find the correct type for the return value of a function like this:
async function initializeBlockSubscription(
  wssEndpoint: string,
  abortSignal: AbortSignal
) {
  const subscription = createSolanaRpcSubscriptions_UNSTABLE(wssEndpoint);

  const notifications = subscription.blockNotifications(
    { mentionsAccountOrProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ADDRESS.toString() },
    {
      encoding: 'base64',
      commitment: 'confirmed',
      showRewards: false,
      transactionDetails: 'full',
      maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0
    }
  );

  const res = await notifications.subscribe({ abortSignal });

  return res;
}

What I’ve Tried:

Type Inference: My IDE (Jetbrains Webstorm) tries to infer the type of res, but the result is deeply nested and tied to generics that are not exported.
Searching for Exported Types: I couldn’t find a clearly exported or basic type for the return value of notifications.subscribe in the library documentation or type declarations.
Inspecting Source Code: The type seems to be generic or heavily dependent on internal library implementation, which makes it difficult to extract.

My Questions:

Is there a basic or recommended type for the return value of notifications.subscribe that I might have missed?
What’s the best way to deal with return types in libraries like this, where types are deeply nested or undocumented?
Are there any established practices for working with Solana’s web3.js types when they are not clearly exported or straightforward?

Notes:

I’m using TypeScript in strict mode, so having a proper type definition is important for my project.
I’d prefer not to rely on any or unknown unless absolutely necessary.

Any insights or workarounds would be greatly appreciated!
UPD:
Here’s another use case where I need this type. Even if we successfully infer the return type of the initializeBlockSubscription function, we still need to determine the correct type for the blocks parameter in the processBlocks function:
async function processBlocks(blocks): Promise<void> { // <-- I need to specify a type for the `blocks` parameter
  for await (const block of blocks) {
    // handle blocks
  }
}

UPD2:
Thanks to @steveluscher for good explanation of the concept of inferring types and matching a needed type overload by a pattern.
There are two options: either adjust ESLint to allow omitting function return types for inference to work or create a utility type to match the desired overload. In my opinion, both options can reduce code clarity, though type inference seems to have minimal impact on readability.
For me, the optimal solution was to define this type:
type TBlockNotification = Awaited<ReturnType<typeof initializeBlockSubscription>>;

Usage:
async function processBlocks(blocks: TBlockNotification): Promise<void> {
  for await (const block of blocks) {
    // handle blocks
  }
}


This isn't really a Solana question so much as a TypeScript question, but I wrote an answer below on how to use TypeScript to extract the type of a particular function overload. That technique is generally applicable to any code that you write.

Exporting ‘result types’ from @solana/web3.js is impractical, because the RPC is fluid to the point where its result types change depending on the particular inputs to the calls themselves.
You can use TypeScript to match on particular overloads and extract the return types of the functions called thusly. What follows is not specific to @solana/web3.js but is more of a tour the TypeScript language features that let you do this.
Setup
Let's simplify the setup to this. Consider an API that you can call either with a number or a boolean.
// Here is an API definition like the one found in @solana/web3.js
type MyCoolApi = {
    cool(x: string, y: number): { numbers: 'are great' }
    cool(x: string, y: boolean): { booleans: 'are neat' }
}

// Let's create an instance of an 'rpc' that implements the `MyCoolApi`
const rpc = null as unknown as MyCoolApi;

// Here's the function that produces the API result
function particularResultProducer() /* no return type */ {
    return rpc.cool(
        'neat',
        true, /* triggers the overload that uses a boolean in this position */
    );
}

Simple solution
The simplest thing you can do is to let TypeScript infer the result type on the basis of the actual producer function you've written. Use the built-in ReturnType utility for this.
type BoolCallResult = ReturnType<typeof particularResultProducer>;

Complex solution
The other thing you can do is to pattern match on the overloads themselves, absent a reference to the producer function.
// Here's a utility type that will let you match on one particular overload.
type ExtractBoolCallResult<T> =
    // If T extends the particular overload with a boolean in the second position...
    T extends (x: string, y: boolean) =>
        // ...then infer the type of that function's return type.
        infer R
    // If a signature was matched resolve this type to whatever was inferred for R
    ? R
    // Otherwise fail. 
    : never;

type BoolCallResult = ExtractBoolCallResult<MyCoolApi['cool']>;

Result
In either case, the type you derive does what you want it to.
function particularResultConsumer(result: BoolCallResult) {
    const neatness = result.booleans;
    neatness satisfies 'are neat'; // OK
}

particularResultConsumer(particularResultProducer()); // OK
particularResultConsumer({ booleans: 'are neat' }); // OK

particularResultConsumer({ numbers: 'are great' }); // ERROR

Playground
You can play with these concepts live, here: link
Notes

You wrote: “My IDE (Jetbrains Webstorm) tries to infer the type of res, but the result is deeply nested and tied to generics that are not exported.” If you do not have TypeScript configured to walk your dependency tree, you must. Make sure that you have a tsconfig.json file in the root of your project and that moduleResolution is set one of the Node variants to make sure that it walks your node_modules directory looking for typedefs.


You’re right — type inference is the easiest solution, but I’d need to adjust ESLint to allow functions without explicit return types, which can hurt code clarity.
Creating a utility type for specific overloads isn’t a good option either—it feels overly complex and hard to maintain.
My solution was to define:
type TBlockNotification = Awaited<ReturnType<typeof initializeBlockSubscription>>;

I think you probably want this type:
type BlockNotification = ReturnType<BlockNotificationsApi['blockNotifications']>;
In my IDE this looks like this:
type BlockNotification = {
    readonly context: Readonly<{
        slot: Slot;
    }>;
    readonly value: Readonly<{
        err: string | null;
        slot: Slot;
    }> & Readonly<{
        block: (Readonly<{
            blockHeight: bigint;
            blockTime: UnixTimestamp;
            blockhash: Blockhash;
            parentSlot: Slot;
            previousBlockhash: Blockhash;
        }> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...>) | null;
    }>;
}

You can see the source here, which has all the inner types and the (quite a lot of!) overloads: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/bd5dff581340d94f5b4d60606c9cde0438b20242/packages/rpc-subscriptions-api/src/block-notifications.ts#L81

I’ve tried using: type TBlockSubscription = ReturnType<BlockNotificationsApi['blockNotifications']>; However, as you pointed out, this isn’t correct because blockNotifications has multiple overloads. Since my use case explicitly involves the overload where encoding is base64, I need a way to extract the specific return type for that overload.
I've updated my question and included one more use case; maybe it will be helpful.
